# Tracking email with SendGrid alike MailGun

Tags: api, events, sendgrid, webhooks, mailgun

I'm studying some email services, as SensdGrid and MailGun.

In MailGun docs I found a really usefull function: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#events

You can simply ask to MailGun API the events triggered, sending also some filters. It is really simple and powerful. Here an example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

public class EventsDateTimeRecipientChunk
{

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (EventsDateTimeRecipient ().Content.ToString ());
    }

    public static IRestResponse EventsDateTimeRecipient ()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient ();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri ("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
        client.Authenticator =
            new HttpBasicAuthenticator ("api",
                                        "YOUR_API_KEY");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest ();
        request.AddParameter ("domain", "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.Resource = "{domain}/events";
        request.AddParameter ("begin", "Fri, 3 May 2013 09:00:00 -0000");
        request.AddParameter ("ascending", "yes");
        request.AddParameter ("limit", 25);
        request.AddParameter ("pretty", "yes");
        request.AddParameter ("recipient", "joe@example.com");
        return client.Execute (request);
    }

}
```

and an output sample:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [],
      "timestamp": 1376325780.160809,
      "envelope": {
        "sender": "me@samples.mailgun.org",
        "transport": ""
      },
      "event": "accepted",
      "campaigns": [],
      "user-variables": {},
      "flags": {
        "is-authenticated": true,
        "is-test-mode": false
      },
      "message": {
        "headers": {
          "to": "user@example.com",
          "message-id": "20130812164300.28108.52546@samples.mailgun.org",
          "from": "Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>",
          "subject": "Hello"
        },
        "attachments": [],
        "recipients": [
          "user@example.com"
        ],
        "size": 69
      },
      "recipient": "user@example.com",
      "method": "http"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next":
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/events/W3siY...",
    "previous":
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/events/Lkawm..."
  }
}
```

Is it possible I can't find the same feature in SendGrid? I'm getting crazy searching in their documents.. I found the webhooks, but it isn't what I need. I only want to see the email status with a http request like MailGun does.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you figured it out by now,

Yet here's for the future :
You should use the webhooks, as follows:

1 configure the apps: clicktrack, opentrack& .what_you_want_to_tarck.. & eventnotify to true, with Get & activate

2 create a POSTURL using RequestPin,

3  activate the event notification from mail settings in  dashboard &  check  the events you want , when you  press the testYourIntegration button, you should get the example post request to the created url.

4. use this code as described in the official documentation:

   string apikey = "......."
       sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get( apikey ))
       to_email = Email("....@gmail.com")
       from_email =Email ("....")
       subject= '...'
         content = Content("text/plain","Trying SendGrid")
       mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
       response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())

   Now , go &  open or click the email sent by code, to declench the event .., then go back

   https://requestb.in/Your_bin_id?inspect

& you should see the notifications after a little while

for more, you can then go to :

```
https://requestb.in/api/v1/bins/bin_id/requests
```

do a Get request with code & just parse the JSON